# "hot-swapping" observables into my subject

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following subject with a one-time "never-going-away" type subscription.

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();
subject.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, () => Con.WriteLine("OnComplete"));
```

Now the above code is followed by this code

```
var sub = Observable.Return(0).Subscribe(subject);
sub.Dispose();
sub = Observable.Return(1).Subscribe(subject);
```

I only see 0 in my console then I see "OnComplete", I do not see 1. Because when the subscription of an observable into a subject is disposed, subject possibly calls `OnComplete` to all it's subscribers. Is there anyway to keep the subscription to a `Subject` alive?

I don't necessarily have to use a subject though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `Observable.Return(0)` produces an `.OnNext(0)` followed by an `.OnCompleted()` which the `subject` gets - and since the contract in Rx is zero or more `.OnNext()` followed by one of either `.OnCompleted()` or `.OnError()`. After that there can be no more `.OnNext()`.

So, instead you have to use a method that avoids the `.OnCompleted()` from each observable you want to add.

First you change your subject:

```
var subject = new Subject<IObservable<int>>();
```

Now the subscription changes to include a `.Switch()`:

```
subject
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(
        Console.WriteLine,
        () => Console.WriteLine("OnComplete"));
```

The `.Switch()` flattens the `IObservable<IObservable<int>>` to `IObservable<int>` by only outputting values from the most recent inner observable, but only completing when the outer observable completes.

Then you use it like this:

```
subject.OnNext(Observable.Return(0));
subject.OnNext(Observable.Return(1));
subject.OnCompleted();
```

Now you get this output:

```
0
1
OnComplete
```

Easy!

Comment: ...and delete the subject completely. :-D